# Why does using a pillar value in this salt environment fail with "... has no attribute ..."?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a new Debian (9.3) install with new salt-master (2017.7.4) and salt-minion installed.  In `/etc/salt/minion.d` I have a conf file containing:

```
master: 127.0.0.1
grains:
  roles:
    - 'introducer'
```

In `/srv/salt/top.sls` I have:

```
base:
  # https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html
  'G@roles:introducer':
    - 'introducer'
```

In `/srv/pillar/data.sls` I have:

```
introducer:
    location: 'tcp:x.x.x.x:y'
    port: 'tcp:y'
```

When I run `salt '*' state.apply`, I encounter this failure:

```
668629:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:introducer' failed: Jinja variable 'salt.pillar object' has no attribute 'introducer'
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

Why isn't the pillar data available?

Comment: I think you should not use quotes in the grains value in /etc/salt/minion.d

Comment: It's yaml isn't it?

Comment: yes. I use it without quotes in both top files and grain files. Just saw that you didn't have your pillar/top.sls. Good to know that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Pillar data requires a top definition as well.  The configuration described in the question has no Pillar `top.sls` so no Pillar data is selected for any of the minions.

To correct this, add a `top.sls` to the Pillar directory which selects the desired minions and makes the data available to them.  For example, this `/srv/pillar/top.sls`:

```
base:
  '*':
    - 'data'
```

This makes the contents of `/srv/pillar/data.sls` available to all minions (selected by `*`) in the base environment.